# loop web page R

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping

I want to apply a loop to scrape data from multiple webpages in R. I'm running the next code:

```
 city <- c("Spokane+Valley",    "Spokane+-+West" ,  "Stanwood", "Steilacoom",   "Stevenson",    "Sudden+Valley",    "Sultan",   "Sumas",    "Summit",   "Summitview",   "Sumner",   "Sunnyside",    "Sunnyslope",   "Suquamish",    "Tacoma+-+Central", "Tacoma+-+East",    "Tacoma+-+NE",  "Tacoma+-+NW",  "Tacoma+-+SE",  "Tacoma+-+South",   "Tacoma+-+SW",  "Tacoma+-+West",    "Tanglewilde" , "Tenino",   "Terrace+Heights",  "Thrashers+Corner", "Tokeland", "Toledo" , "Toppenish", "Town+and+Country", "Tracyton" ,    "Trentwood",    "Tukwila",  "Tulalip+Bay"  ,    "Tulalip+Indian+Reservation",   "Tumwater", "Twisp",    "Union+Gap"  ,  "University+Place", "Vancouver", "Vancouver+Mall",  "Veradale", "Walla+Walla",  "Walla+Walla+East", "Waller",   "Walnut+Grove", "Wapato",   "Warden",   "Washougal",    "Wenatchee",    "West+Clarkston-Highland",  "West+Lake+Sammamish",  "West+Longview",    "West+Pasco",   "West+Richland",    "West+Side+Highway",    "West+Valley",  "Westport", "White+Center-Shorewood",   "White+Salmon", "White+Swan",   "Winlock",  "Winslow",  "Winthrop", "Woodinville",  "Woodland", "Woodmont+Beach",   "Yakima",   "Yelm", "Zillah")

 for(i in city){
 url <- ("http://www.washingtongasprices.com/GasPriceSearch.aspx?typ=adv&fuel=D&srch=0&area=",i,"&site=Washington&station=All%20Stations&tme_limit=36")
}
```

But I having this message:

Error: unexpected ',' in:
"for(i in city){
  url <- ("http://www.washingtongasprices.com/GasPriceSearch.aspx?typ=adv&fuel=D&srch=0&area=","

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to paste your URL together

```
url <- paste0("http://www.washingtongasprices.com/GasPriceSearch.aspx?typ=adv&fuel=D&srch=0&area=",i,"&site=Washington&station=All%20Stations&tme_limit=36")
```